# Call a generic extension method on another generic extension method's parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm doing some ASP.NET MVC 3, and I'm setting up a couple extension methods for working with Enums. One of them is a fancy ToString() that looks for a [Description] attribute, and the other builds a SelectList from an enum for use with Html.DropDownList(). Both of these methods are in the same static class.

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum? enumval) where TEnum : struct {
    var values = from TEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)) select new { ID = e, Name = e.GetDescription() };
    SelectList list = new SelectList(values, "ID", "Name", enumval);
    return list;
}

public static string GetDescription<TEnum>(this TEnum? enumval) where TEnum : struct {
    //Some reflection that fetches the [Description] attribute, or returns enumval.ToString() if it isn't defined.
}
```

But the compiler squawks about `Name = e.GetDescription()`, stating that...

> 'TEnum' does not contain a definition for 'GetDescription' and no extension method 'GetDescription' accepting a first argument of type 'TEnum' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This doesn't come as a huge surprise, but I'm not sure how to get the compiler to recognize GetDescription() as a valid extension method for the enumval parameter of ToSelectList(). I realize I could probably make this work by moving the guts of GetDescription() into a private static method, and making the extension method just a wrapper to that, but chaining generic extension methods seems like something I ought to know how to do properly.

Comment: The variable e is of type TEnum.  The GetDescription extension method is for Nullable<TEnum> and not TEnum.  Can you make GetDescription an extension of just TEnum (not Nullable<TEnum>)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e` is not a nullable struct; it's just a struct.  `GetDescription` takes a nullable struct.

Either make `e` nullable, or make a non-nullable version of `GetDescription`.

Comment: Yup, I'm a dope. I changed `from TEnum e` to `from TEnum? e` and that got me going. Thanks.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal SO made me wait about 10 minutes before marking it.

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you're using a `Nullable<TEnum>` as the parameter?  I'm having trouble thinking of why you'd want to call either of these extension methods on a null value.

If you get rid of the nullable requirement, you can make them non-generic and based on the `Enum` type directly, which is friendlier (including letting you use extension method syntax with enum values in the usual way):

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList(this Enum enumval)
{
  var values = from Enum e in Enum.GetValues(enumval.GetType()) select new { ID = e, Name = e.GetDescription() };
  SelectList list = new SelectList(values, "ID", "Name", enumval);
  return list;
}

public static string GetDescription(this Enum enumval)
{
  //Some reflection that fetches the [Description] attribute, or returns enumval.ToString() if it isn't defined.
}
```

Then you can do:

```
MyEnum enumval = MyEnum.Whatever;
var list = enumval.ToSelectList();
```

...which I don't think you can do with your current generic version -- you'd have to invoke it with:

```
MyEnum enumval = MyEnum.Whatever;
var list = ((MyEnum?)enumval).ToSelectList();
```

Comment: I'm actually using a nullable enum in this case. The enum represents project task item status (Needed, Not Needed, Addressed...), and the null value represents "not yet set". But I like how this cleans up the code; I'll consider adding a "Not Set" value to the enum and doing it this way. I'm just interface prototyping right now, so it's still early enough to change.

Comment: Gotcha.  I always like to keep things general if I can, just in case someday I'm working with a non-nullable version of the enum.  I suppose there's no reason you couldn't have both versions of the extension methods too.